# Flutter ListView entries cut off when scrolled down

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

A screen in my app displays a list of "listings" the user has made.  In the event there is not enough listings to fill the whole screen, and the user scrolls down, the listing they are scrolling will get cut off instead of being scrolled down.

[example before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piR8n.png)

[example after scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhpvB.png)

As the user scrolls the list entry downwards I would like it not to disappear.  I've tried wrapping the listview.builder in containers / sized boxes to define their size, although this behavior persists.  I thought I could also put in some blank entries into the list that wouldn't respond to user clicks but that seems like an inefficient solution.  Here is my code:

```
    return Scaffold(
        key: listing_home_scaffold_key,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: BODY_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
        appBar: returnAppBarForHomePages(context, "Listings", widget.local_user, updateUserState,
            widget.local_user.usingDefaultImage, widget.local_user.getProfilePicURL, listing_home_scaffold_key),
        drawer: settingsDrawer(widget.local_user),
        body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              returnScrollableListView()
            ]),
      );

  Widget returnScrollableListView() {
    return RefreshIndicator(
          child: ListView.builder(
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
              itemCount: user_listings.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return UserListing(listing: user_listings[index]);
              }),
          onRefresh: () async {
            var cancel_loading_indicator = showLoadingIndicatorAllowClick();
            await reQueryData();
            cancel_loading_indicator();
          },
        );
  }
```

Edit: Having the refresh indicator be the direct parent to the listview caused this problem.  Moving it up a level so it's instead the parent of the Column fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

Having the refresh indicator be the direct parent to the listview caused this problem. Moving it up a level so it's instead the parent of the Column fixed this.